# Cherry-Picking commit from someone's PR

Tags: git, github

I am working on a github repository (not mine) and want to cherry-pick some commits from someone else's PR (so that the ownership remains) and then make a new PR with some more changes. I am currently on a branch `modular` and the PR from which I want to cherry-pick is `abc: eq_modular`.

I have tried using the command,

```
>>> git cherry-pick xyz
fatal: bad object xyz
```

where xyz is the hash for the commit I want to pick.

I couldn't find any solution for the problem. So if anyone could suggest anything on the issue it would be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the button to merge a pull request, there's a link to "command line instructions". It shows how to bring the commits from the pull request into your local copy so you can start working with them (e.g. cherry pick them).

```
git checkout -b abc-modular master
git pull git@github.com:abc/repo.git eq_modular
```

Now you have a new branch "abc-modular" that contains all the commits from the pull request. Feel free to cherry pick them, rebase, fixup, or squash as you like.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is `develop` in the first command because it's returning an error. `fatal: 'develop' is not a commit and a branch 'abc-modular' cannot be created from it` and using the commit hash in place of `develop` gives `fatal: reference is not a tree`

Comment: Ah, it's the name of the branch the pull request wants to merge into. Maybe it's `master` in your project?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by following commands

```
git fetch git@github.com:user_name/repo.git branch_name
git cherry-pick commit-hash
```